# Collapsible div inside of bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to add a collapsible div inside of my bootstrap table. I am attempting to do this within my first column after the header titled `"COLLAPSE HERE`" I've wrapped the down icon in an `anchor` tag attempting to have the icon be the toggle of the collapsible. I then nested a `<div></div>` wrapping around the row of table that that i'd like to appear / hide on toggle. Currently, this has no effect on my table. I am using bootstraps method of [collapsable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/) but if this can be achieved in javascript that works fine.

Here is a code snippet of my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <table class="table table-hover">
            <colgroup>
                <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
                <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
                <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
                <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
             </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Second</th>
                    <th scope="col">Third</th>
                    <th scope="col">Four</th>
                    <th scope="col">TITLE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-18">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" id="3digit">COLLAPSE HERE <a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i
                        class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> </a></th>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <th>Online Stores</th>
                </tr>   
               </tbody>         
               <tbody>  
                   <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <th>Retail</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <th scope="row">3 </th>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <th>Appointment</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <th scope="row">4</th>
                    <th>Orders</th>
                </tr>
            </div>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

My expected outcome is to have everything under the first row under the "COLLAPSE HERE" title and icon to collapse the table.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vanilla JavaScript option that adds some animation to the collapse.

I grab the **div** you wish to **collapse**, and the **class** for the **chevron**.
I use `querySelector()` as there is only one of each of these classes in your code and this selector method will return the first iteration of that class. I then add an **eventListener** `click` and add a **conditional** to check if the targeted element, **`.col`** has **opacity** set to **`0`**. If it is set to `0` we set a transition to **`all .5s ease-in-out`**, a half second ease-in-out on the opacity. We set the `Y overflow` to **hidden** and then toggle the **chevron** by removing the up and adding the down, using **`.remove()`** and **`.add()`** on the **`event.target`** => ***chevron***.

***else*** we also add a *transition animation* and reverse the **`fas`** classes again using **`.add()`** and **`.remove()`**.

```js
let col = document.querySelector('.col');
let fas = document.querySelector('.fas');
let digit3 = document.getElementById('digit3');

const collapsable = (e) => {
  fas.classList.toggle('fa-chevron-down');
  if (col.style.opacity === '0') {
    col.style.opacity = '1';
    digit3.children[0].innerText = 'COLLAPSE HERE';
    col.style.transition = 'all .5s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
    e.target.classList.remove('fa-chevron-down');
    e.target.classList.add('fa-chevron-up');
  } else {
    col.style.opacity = '0';
    digit3.children[0].innerText = 'EXPAND HERE';
    col.style.transition = 'all .5s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.transition = '-o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out';
    col.style.maxHeight = '0px';
    e.target.classList.remove('fa-chevron-up');
    e.target.classList.add('fa-chevron-down');
  }
}

fas.addEventListener('click', collapsable);
```

```css
.fas {
 margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<table class="table table-hover">
  <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 116px;">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Second</th>
      <th scope="col">Third</th>
      <th scope="col">Four</th>
      <th scope="col">TITLE</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-18">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" id="digit3"><span>COLLAPSE HERE</span><a data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-controls="collapseExample"><i
                        class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i> </a></th>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <th scope="row"></th>
      <th>Online Stores</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="col">
    <div id="collapseExample">
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <th>Retail</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <th scope="row">3 </th>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <th>Appointment</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <th>Orders</th>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```